# Magento 2 Category SEO friendly URLS

Tags: php, database, magento2

I have a Magento 2 website and require some direction with setting up sub-category urls to be SEO friendly. The Navigation menu work just fine i.e

Grooming Kit

www.mywebsite.com/product-grooming-kit.html the issue i'm having is with sub-categories in the left sidebar filters which when a specific category is clicked on it displays as following url with a number id

www.mywebsite.com/product-grooming-kit.html?grooming-kit=32

I want it to look like

www.mywebsite.com/product-grooming-kit/grooming-kit-mens/

I have added this to custom urls manually, cleared cache and still no changes?

In Magento 1.9 i would do a reindexer using ssh and would update urls. Not sure how to do this in Magento 2 without installing a third party extension.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks
Vinnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at:

system->config->catalog->seo->use category paths in product url->yes

and then also important:
system->config->catalog->seo->canonical for categories/products->yes

For the URL Rewrites, you should use an extension. I recommend [OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites) but only if you are using a version up to Magento 2.2.4. Then you should use OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites Version 1.3.0.

Please look also at a SEO extension that resolves the duplicate content issue if you are using multiple store views for different languages. ([Maybe this one](https://github.com/staempfli/magento2-module-seo)).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response I have made the changes as suggested above. After installing the the URL Rewrites extension and regenerating urls, clearing all cache  etc I still not seeing any changes to the url and still get www.mywebsite.com/product-grooming-kit.html?grooming-kit=32

Comment: So to get it clear: you are clicking on the category in magento's filternavigation? Or do you have a sidebar menu?

Comment: Its under a brand section in magento's filter navigation in the left sidebar. hope that makes sense? So when i click on one of the brand i get the following attached to the end of the url i.e ?grooming-kit=32

Comment: Check this out: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208102/magento-2-layered-navigation-seo-friendly-urls?rq=1

Comment: thank you for pointing me i the right direction. I will take a look at it later today and let you know how i get on?